# Make URL visually change as I go back etc. In web browser C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, url, browser

I am making a web browser in WPF C# and would need help with getting the URL to change in the address bar when you press back or press a link. Any help would be appreciated.

Code for button linked to textbox:

```
    private void OnImageButtonClick_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        try
        {
            if (Urlbox.Text.Contains("http://") == false)
            {
                WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://" + Urlbox.Text);
            }
            else WebBrowser1.Navigate(Urlbox.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Please insert URL");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you have got so far

Comment: Not a lot to show, it is simply a textbox linked to a button in the browser. Code in original post.

Comment: Is that .Net or WPF? you have .net taged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my example project is to set the trust of the application to FullTrust.

Go to your project settings > Securtity and check 'This is a full trust application'